# One document.getElementById per function?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to use mouse coordinates to control the opacity of div elements, but only one div element will respond.

```
<head>
document.onmousemove=getMouseCoordinates;

function getMouseCoordinates(event)
{
ev = event || window.event;
var width = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById('divOne').style.opacity = ev.pageX/width;
document.getElementById('divOne').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
document.getElementById('divTwo').style.opacity = ev.pageX/width;
document.getElementById('divTwo').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
}
</head>
<body>
<div id="divOne" style="position:fixed; top:7%; left: 11%;"><img src="images/skytest.png" /></div>
<div id="divTwo" style="position:fixed; top:22%; left: 26%;"><img src="images/0816112011d.jpeg" /></div>
```

divOne does what I would expect, but divTwo does nothing.
Anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: document.getElementById only returns one element -- jQuery will return and act on an array.

Comment: What is the `HTML` in your question?

Comment: Are you saying you have more than one element with ID `skyMan-1`? IDs have to be unique! Because of that, `getElementById` will always only return one (usually the first) element with that ID.

Comment: @Felix King -No there's only one element with ID skyman. I've simplified the code to make the problem more evident.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: There's nothing different between divOne and divTwo in your code so the ONLY reason one would work and the other wouldn't has to be something to do with your HTML for divTwo.  We'd probably have to see that HTML in order to help.

Comment: Put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the only problem is that the js isn't in a script tag.  Otherwise there's no difference.

See this [very easy to make demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qced9/) :D

Comment: I did have script tags, the problem had to do with the second call to each div style, which changed the alpha. For some reason removing this code makes it work, but I've added the code back in to show what I mean. Maybe the ...style.alpha() is unnecessary? I'm not sure. Thanks for your help @Joseph